# Deployment 10GbE (10Gbps) ethernet for 10km fiber requirements

Tags: networking

To deploy 10GbE (10 Gigabit ethernet) for a distance of 10km connecting two control centers, is it safe to assume that G.652 fiber would not be suitable and G.655 fiber (at 1550nm) is required instead?

Comment: This would be better suited on the network exchange, not a lot of Layer 1 guys here.

Answer (score 8):

10GBASE-LR can reach 10 km. It uses 1310 nm wavelength with a total power budget of 9.4 dB. It assumes a maximum attenuation if .4 db/km (OS2).

If you've got OS1 deployed you'll need 10GBASE-ER (1550 nm) instead.

For a new deployment you should aim for the highest quality fiber you can get/budget. Redeployment in a few years will cost much more than the current price difference. With constantly rising requirements, today's 10G line will have to carry 40G or even 100G in a couple of years.

Comment: "Redeployment in a few years will cost much more than the current price difference." - I think a lot of people miss this one. If people think the cost of doing things properly is expensive, they should see the price of paying for a bodge job then paying to rip out the bodge job and doing it properly anyway.

Comment: Exactly. Usually you should plan your cabling to last at least 10 years and we all don't know what we'll need then.